# Passing 'this' wrapped as unique_ptr C++

Tags: c++, recursion, unique-ptr

I have a class that acts as a node in a binary tree, one of the methods which I would like to call from inside that class is recursive, and needs to pass itself to the next node in the tree so that the next node knows its own parent. I dont want to store a class member parent because I would like to avoid using a shared_ptr.

The code looks something like this:

```
void MyClass::expand(MyClass* parent){
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size; i ++){
        children[i]->doSomethingWithParent(parent);
        children[i]->expand(this);
    }
    return;
}
```

But I would like to pass a unique_ptr instead of a raw pointer. However, the pointer to 'this' is already wrapped elsewhere by a unique_ptr already, so I dont want to instantiate another. Is it possible to do this?

If there are any design patterns I should be aware of please let me know.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Not a good design. Use shared_ptr and enable_shared_from_this as a base class of MyClass.

Comment: "I would like to pass a unique_ptr instead of a raw pointer" Why? It's not like `expand()` takes ownership of the passed pointer. Raw pointers are not evil. It's raw pointers that express ownership that are to be avoided.

Comment: Is children a members of MyClass? If so, children must never own or share this.

Comment: Using `unique_ptr` is asking for a disaster to happen. You've handed over ownership of the object to that wrapper.

Comment: Only use *smart pointers* to manage the lifetime/deletion of objects. Don't pass them around unless you absolutely have to. Pass the raw pointer.

Comment: @Frank what is meant by 'ownership'? I presume every class member is owned by its class, but are there any other cases?

Comment: @m.tracey A good shorthand for 'ownership' is "where the object is deleted from". If you call `delete` on a raw pointer, or pass that pointer to something that will eventually call delete on the object, then that pointer was, if only briefly, the "owner" of the object. On the flip side, if a pointer is never in the "path to deletion" of the object, then it being a raw pointer is no problem (barring dangling pointer concerns, obviously).

Comment: `return;` as last statement is pointless. you might remove it.

Comment: for-range is appropriate: `for (auto& child : children) { child->doSomethingWithParent(parent); child->expand(this); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a pointer at all. You are not taking ownership, the argument is not optional, so use a reference:

```
void MyClass::expand(MyClass& parent){
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size; i ++){
        children[i]->doSomethingWithParent(parent);
        children[i]->expand(*this);
    }
    return;
}
```

All of your code will perform the same, and it is safer etc.

Comment: *"the argument is not optional"*. Root doesn't have parent, so pointer is legit.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever have a situation where you want to pass a non-owning pointer that is guaranteed to be non-null (which appears to be the case here), then you probably want to just use a reference instead.

In your case, depending on what `doSomethingWithParent` performs, you'd probably actually want a const reference as well:

```
void MyClass::doSomethingWithParent(const MyClass& parent) {
  // who knows?
}

void MyClass::expand(const MyClass& parent) {
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size; i ++){
        children[i]->doSomethingWithParent(parent);
        children[i]->expand(*this);
    }
}
```